# Determine HttpContext.Current.Handler is my or system's

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler, ihttpmodule

I want to add some headers to the response of my `.aspx` and `.ashx` files in my `IHttpModule`. How can I filter `.axd` and all other system handlers in `IsSystemHandler()`? I can do `HttpContext.Current.Handler is Page` for `.aspx`, but what about `.ashx`?

```
public class MySecurityModule : IHttpModule 
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.PreSendRequestHeaders += PreSendRequestHeaders;
    }

    void PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Handler == null)
            return;
        if (IsSystemHandler())
            return;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add(.....);
    }

    bool IsSystemHandler()
    {
        // How to filter system handlers here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsSystemHandler()
{
    Type t = context.Handler.GetType();
    while (t != null && t.Assembly != this.GetType().Assembly)
        t = t.BaseType;
    if (t == null)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.